# MS Access 2016 Query

Tags: ms-access-2016

Good Evening,

I have an access database that tracks each employee assigned to a job each day.  Each job can have up to 20 employees assigned to it each day.  I need to list on a form each of the employees assigned to each job.

I have two tables, tbl_employees and tbl_jobs.  The table, tbl_jobs, records each employee assigned to a job via the  employee_id.    Please see below...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycMmE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD1gJ.png)

I need to create a query that shows the lastName of each employee assigned to each job.

Below was my first attempt.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqmzp.png)

It did not work.  Below is the result.  Obviously it is not what I am looking for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3OiD.png)

Below was my next attempt...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okQLS.png)

It did not work either.  Here is the result.  I only get one job returned when I need two returned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJpYg.png)

I made other attempts that are variations of these but they too failed to return each employee assigned to each job.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to do it correctly, please?

Comment: You really need to redesign this, or you will face endless troubles. Search for "How to normalise a database" or similar.

Comment: Gustav...Thanks for the response.  Redesign how?

Comment: Sorry for another question.  But by redesign do you mean have a separate table for employees assigned to the job?

Comment: Yes, by their IDs. Using a relational database like Access is about normalising data.